# Modal in javascript

Tags: javascript, roxy-fileman

I am trying to create a modal in JavaScript and using the roxy file manager for my website admin panel . Modal dialog is not opening  .

**code**

```
<script>
    function openCustomRoxy2(){
      $('#roxyCustomPanel2').dialog({modal:true, width:875,height:600});
    }
    function closeCustomRoxy2(){
      $('#roxyCustomPanel2').dialog('close');
    }
 </script>



<input type="text" id="txtSelectedFile"  value="Click here to select a 
file" onclick="openCustomRoxy2()">
<div id="roxyCustomPanel2" >
  <iframe src="fileman/index.html?integration=custom&type=files&txtFieldId=txtSelectedFile" ></iframe> 

 </div>
```

dailog is not opening .

Answer (score 0):

A modal wont load if there are errors in your JavaScript. this doesn't necessarily have to be in the code that loads your modal but it will be in the JS added. So bascially after your page loads you need to look for a JS error shown in any developer window like (firebug/console) or develeoper tools/console(chrome) to have a look at the errors. fix the JS errors first and your code will most likely start working.